# How do I use putStrLn on Maybe value in Haskell Stack test?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I am using the Haskell Stack to create a program. My program builds okay but I would like to write a test file so that I can run `stack test` on my existing program. My problem is that my function to test returns a Maybe type, which cannot be outputted using the syntax `putStrLn f`. I am attempting to write a function in my test file that takes a Maybe value and returns "Nothing" if it was given Nothing, or a string containing a if it was given Just a.

Here is my code so far:

```
printMaybe :: Show a => Maybe a -> String
printMaybe Nothing = "Nothing"
printMaybe (Just a) = show a
```

and main contains the line
`putStrLn $ printMaybe (Nothing)`

My error message is:

> test\Spec.hs:12:16: error:
> * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of` printMaybe'
> prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved. Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what` a0' should be.
> These potential instances exist:
> instance Show Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Show' instance Show Integer -- Defined in` GHC.Show'
> instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show' ...plus 22 others ...plus 27 instances involving out-of-scope types (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all) * In the second argument of` ($)', namely `printMaybe (Nothing)'
> In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ printMaybe (Nothing)
> In the expression:
> do putStrLn ("====== Tests Start ======")
> putStrLn $ printMaybe (Nothing)
> |
> 12 |     putStrLn $ printMaybe (Nothing)
> |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: As the error says, the problem is not with your `printMaybe`, it is with `printMaybe Nothing` in your `do` block, since then it is unclear what the `a` type is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the problem is not with your `printMaybe`, it is with `printMaybe Nothing` in your `do` block, since then it is unclear what the `a` type is.

You thus likely have something like:K

```
main = do
    putStrLn "====== Tests Start ======"
    putStrLn (printMaybe Nothing)
```

But it is unclear what the `a` of the type `Maybe a` is for `Nothing`. You can give a hint to the compiler with:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "====== Tests Start ======"
    putStrLn (printMaybe (Nothing :: Maybe Int))
```